# Setting up tracking for working in my own branch in git

Tags: git

I have been trying to figure out how to do this but none of the answer I have seen have satisfied what I want.

So we are trying to work in our own branches in git. I have branch `me` and when I run `git pull` I want to track the remote branch `develop`. Then when I run `Git push` I want to push onto the remote of `me` that will later get pull requested into `develop` I could setup `me` to track `develop` then when I push run `git push origin me` or setup a git macro but I would like to know if there is a way to setup my config so that vanilla push/pull will do what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I even start, I'll note one thing here: if you run:

```
git push origin me:me
```

then *none of the push-related stuff below matters at all*.  But it's kind of a pain (see the "B&D" note below).

#### Setting an upstream, and a bunch of background information

Setting any one branch you have to track any other reference you have is easy: just use `git branch --set-upstream-to=<upstream> <branch>`.  But you have another requirement, which creates a bit of a problem.  Fortunately, there is a solution using `push.default`.

The main stumbling block here is the terminology.  Git offers "remotes" (which are actually *local* things), "remote-tracking branches" (which are also local), the `--track` flag to `git checkout` (which sets some things locally), and uses the verb "track" (which means something different from every one of the above things!).  The saving grace here is that in Git, *everything* is local.  Once you keep that self-contradictory bit—that remotes and remote-tracking branches are local—in mind, more things make sense.  The only time Git works any way other than locally is when you connect *two* Gits to each other, primarily using `git fetch` or `git push`.  These two Gits then work locally (of course!), but give each other data, so that one Git's items can make it across to the other's.

We'll get to the second problem soon, but with the above out of the way:

> I have branch `me` and when I run `git pull` I want to track the remote branch develop ...

This is where you would want:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop me
```

(assuming your remote is called `origin`—that's almost always the case).  That means "set the upstream for `me` to `origin/develop`", which is also what Git documentation means when it has the *verb* "track", as in "`me` tracks `origin/develop`".  But if we do this, we're going to have a problem soon.

What `git pull` does is, in essence, to run `git fetch` (which obtains stuff from that other Git), then run `git merge` or—if you tell it so—`git rebase`.  (It runs a deliberately-limited `git fetch`, which buys almost nothing most of the time.  An unlimited `git fetch` might fetch a bit more now, but that saves effort by fetching less later.  I normally recommend that everyone split this into separate `git fetch` and second-Git-command steps, as the effect seems to me to be a lot clearer.  In the end, though, this makes no big difference, except for giving you much more control and visibility in between.)

The `git fetch` step calls up the other Git, by the (local) name you gave it, usually `origin`.  The other Git then says "I have some branches like `develop`, would you like these commits?"  Your Git says "yes" and downloads the commits.  Since your Git has its *own* branches, your Git then *renames* all *their* branches: their `develop` becomes your remote-tracking branch `origin/develop`.  That keeps your remote-tracking branches (which, again, are local) separate from your regular branches (which are also local).

The `git merge` or (`git rebase`) step uses your remote-tracking branch, which you have now set to `origin/develop`, to merge with (or rebase onto) whatever your Git just fetched and put in your `origin/develop`.  So that's why we want to set the upstream.  But wait...

> Then when I run Git push I want to push onto the remote of `me`

Here's where the problem I mentioned comes in.  *By default*, `git push` (which calls up the other Git again) "wants" to offer, to the other Git, your branch and its commits ... and then ask the other Git to set *its* branch *of the same name*.  That's a fine *default*, and would be just right here: you'd ask the Git at `origin` to set its branch named `me`, not its branch named `develop`.  But as soon as we set the upstream, we *change the default*.

Now your Git will call up the other Git, offer it some commits, then ... well, now it gets complicated.  One part of your configuration says "ask them to set their `develop`", because that's the *upstream*.  Another part of your configuration probably—this depends on settings and Git version—tells your Git that it should *only* ask them to update their branch *if the name is `me`*.  Obviously these two are not possible at the same time.

#### Using `push.default`

**Note**: If you run `git push remote refspec`, `push.default` is **ignored**.  It only affects pushes where you leave out the *`refspec`* part.

The configuration variable `push.default` has [five possible settings](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) (since Git version 1.8 or so).  Since Git version 2.0, the default is `simple`.  The five settings are:

- `nothing`: error out.  `git push` or `git push origin` just fails; it makes you type in more.  You *must* enter a refspec.  (I call this the annoying bondage-and-discipline mode.  I tried it for a while but it was too annoying. :-) )
- `current`: push the *current branch* to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end.
- `upstream`: push the current branch to the corresponding upstream branch.
- `simple`: push the current branch to update a branch with the same name, except that if you're pushing to the place you normally fetch from, *demand that upstream name match*.
- `matching`: pay no attention to the *current* branch; push *as many branches* as match branch names in the other Git.  This is partly a historic holdover from Git versions predating 2.0.  If you have branches `a`, `b`, and `c` as well as `me`, and the other Git has branches `b`, `c`, `d`, `develop`, and `master`, your Git would ask their Git to set their `b` and `c` (those being the two matching names).  This mode is pretty powerful and quite handy in some cases, but it's also a bit dangerous, which is why the default changed in 2.0.

If you read through that list carefully, you'll see what what you want is (probably) the `current` setting.  That way, as long as `git status` says `on branch me`, your `git push` (with no extra arguments) will:

- contact the other Git;
- send it your commits; and
- ask it to set its `me` to match your `me`.

This happens no matter what your branch `me` has set as its upstream.

Note that if you have *two* remotes, such as `origin` and `review`, or `origin` and `pull-request-host`, you could still use the default `simple` setting.  This is because your branch `me` has as its upstream `origin/develop`, not `review/*`, not `pull-request-host/*`.  So the special requirement that the two names *match* is applied only on `origin`.  When you are pushing to `review` or to `pull-request-host`, `simple` devolves back to `current`, and tries to push `me` to `me`.

Comment: Its always great to see these massive answers. This is a great help and clears up some confusion I have had about git!

Answer (score 2):

Default pull destinations in `git` are controlled by the “upstream” branch setting for the local branch. If you want to pull from branch `develop` on the remote `origin`, set upstream to `origin/develop`:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop me
```

Default push destinations, on the other hand, are controlled by `push.default` configuration parameter. If you want to push to the remote branch with the same name, set it to `current` (this is at least repository-wide, not branch-wide):

```
$ git config push.default current
```

Read more:

```
$ git help branch
$ git help config
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** - As noted in comments, there are a number of settings that effect each of the three mappings I talk about.  The combination I suggest will work (with an edit to fix a mistake I made when copying refspecs from my test repo), but it ha a side-effect of making `push` work a little differently than the modern default setting.  So you may want to look at the alternatives for that particular setting.

---

There are a few configuration options involved here, so you have plenty of flexibility to do what you're asking.  There are really three mappings that go on:

When you fetch, you map a remote ref (say `develop` as it exists in origin) to a ref in the local repo (say `origin/develop`).  This is controlled (by default) by the config value `remote.origin.fetch`.

When you pull, it first does a fetch (per the above rule) and then decides what to merge into the current branch (you want `origin/develop` merged into `me`).  This is controlled (by default) by the config value `branch.me.merge`.

And when you push, you map your current local branch to a particular ref to be updated on the remote.  Often this can be inferred using some default logic, but you can control it more specifically with config values like `remote.origin.push`.

Note that I am suggesting you *not* change the fetch mapping, because `origin/<branch>` is your window to what's happening on the remote so keeping it in line with the remote's branch names makes the most sense.

So to get the `pull` behavior you want you can

```
git config branch.me.merge refs/heads/develop
```

Now `push` will think things look ambiguous, so you clarify with

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

Comment: I wouldn't change `remote.origin.push` here (though it's certainly possible), as that affects *every* default-push-to-origin. (Also you'd need to make it `refs/heads/me:refs/heads/me` here. Well, I think ... I have not actually tried it!) There are even more control knobs, as you can set a per-branch `branch.<name>.pushDefault`, so there are lots of ways to do this, but they rapidly spiral deep into crazyland. :-)

Comment: @torek - The refspec I was testing with was `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`, but somehow I omitted the `*`s in the original answer (edited). That said, the *intent* was that this should just restore the default rule (which git seems unsure of once the merge setting is changed), but taking another look this seems to reproduce *old* behavior that is no longer the default.  So you're probably right that using a different, more specific setting is better for most situations